# Optimize the resampling and projection of multiple NetCDF files in R using terra

Tags: r, netcdf, resampling, terra, parallel-processing

I have a set of 35 NetCDF files (continental scale), each containing 365 daily layers of climate data with a resolution of 5 km, `s`. I need to do two main tasks:

Subset, `s_sub`, these files based on a specific list of dates,`targeted_dates`.Then, resample, crop and project them to the target resolution (30m), projection, and extent using a reference raster, `reference_raster`.

Using the `terra::project` function to align (resample, crop and project) `s_sub` with `reference_raster` takes about 25 minutes.

The problem is that the process takes an inordinate amount of time—more than 10 days—just to write the rasters, `sp30`, to disk.

Are there other better ways of performing these operations, especially the file-writing step, to make it faster?

Here's the code snippet:

```
nc_files <- list.files("Path", pattern = "*.nc")
s <- rast(nc_files, "pr")


# A single vector of targeted dates
targeted_dates <- as.Date(all_dates)

reference_raster <- rast("path/to/reference_raster")
reference_raster
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1893, 3649, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 666885, 776355, 6718135, 6774925  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : GDA94_MGA_zone_55 
source      : gw_20150906_l8_inundation_ors.img 
color table : 1 
name        : Layer_1 
min value   :       0 
max value   :       2



# Subset rasters needed for the model based on targeted_dates
s_sub <- terra::subset(s, time(s) %in% targeted_dates)
s_sub
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 681, 841, 4883  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.05, 0.05  (x, y)
extent      : 111.975, 154.025, -44.025, -9.975  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
sources     : rain_day_1988.nc  (166 layers) 
              rain_day_1990.nc  (122 layers) 
              rain_day_1991.nc  (94 layers) 
              ... and 27 more source(s)
varnames    : pr (pr) 
              pr (pr) 
              pr (pr) 
              ...
names       : pr_50, pr_51, pr_52, pr_53, pr_54, pr_55, ... 
unit        :      mm,      mm,      mm,      mm,      mm,      mm, ... 
time (days) : 1988-02-19 to 2022-08-20 

# Project and resample using reference_raster
sp30 <- project(s_sub, reference_raster, mask = FALSE, align = FALSE)

# Write each raster to disk
ndays <- terra::time(sp30)
writeRaster(sp30, paste0("pr", ndays, ".tif"), overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: One question per Question, please, as per the [Tour].

Comment: The processing of each of these NetCDFs is independent of the others, so this is trivially parallelisable on a cluster. But without more info about the data and how long all the other parts take to compute we can't begin to attack this as an optimisation problem. A 30m global grid is going to be vast - how big? Do you really need to turn each 10km pixel into 100,000 identical 30m x 30m pixels? How long is it going to take to read and analyse this?

Comment: @Spacedman `s_sub` actually has a 5 km resolution and dimensions of 681x841 with 4883 layers. In contrast, `reference_raster` is considerably smaller with a 30m resolution and dimensions of 1893x3649. Using the `terra` package's `project` function to align (resample, crop and project) `s_sub` with `reference_raster` takes about 25 minutes. However, writing these new `sp30` layers to disk is estimated to take 12 days.

Comment: All those sizes and dimensions and resolutions should be included as basic information for the question, not added as comments. How does `s_sub` get to be 5km resolution since your NetCDFs (in `s`) are said to be 10km resolution? Give enough information in the question so that we can repeat your calculation with similarly-sized objects (which we can create with random pixel values for test purposes). Or better still give code that creates these things in the question instead of depending on data files that we don't have.

Comment: @Spacedman I am working with two distinct sets of data. The first set consists of 35 yrs of historical data with a 5 km resolution, and the second set includes 100 yrs of future scenarios with a 10 km resolution. I will be performing the resampling and cropping tasks for both the historical and future projections. I have updated my question to reflect the specifics of my historical data, which comprises 35 years of NetCDF files. I apologize for any confusion my previous information may have caused due to the mixing of data from these two different sets.

Comment: From your updates `s_sub` has a 0.05 *degree* resolution (its in lat-long) not 5km, and spans a much larger extent than `reference_raster` such that very few pixels of `s_sub` are inside the reference raster, and so the transformed `s_sub` contains very little information. Its then being rescaled to `reference_raster`s 1800x3600. And are you saying it takes 10 days to write `sp30`? And `sp30` is 4800 layers of 1800x3600? That's 30 billion pixels. Have you tried with a subset? What's your computer's spec? Sorry, but its hard to answer Q's like this.

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, it took 12 days to write those 4883 lyrs. I have 32Gb memory and 14 CPU cores.

Comment: OK that's crazy slow, its clearly hitting some limit. On my 8 year old PC with 8Gb RAM and 8 cores writing one 3600x1800 raster takes 0.3s and it scales linearly with the number of layers (tested up to 64 layers) which would extrapolate to about 40 minutes for 4800 layers. Try breaking it all down and doing a layer (or each of your 35 files) at a time. Its all independent of layers so you can do this "trivially". Writing 4883 tif files might be a thousand times faster than writing one 4883-layer tiff.

Comment: @Spacedman, Many thanks for your suggestion. By implementing a for-loop to extract layers from the multi-layer raster `s_sub`, resampling and projecting them to match the `reference_raster` and then writing each processed layer to a separate TIFF file, I was able to reduce the processing time to just 2 and a half hours.